# How can I su to user and then sudo command without asking for password?

Tags: linux, command-line, sudo

I want to run sudo as a user after changing to them from root without asking for their password or changing any settings.

**Step 1: change  to user, from root**

```
server:~#su joseph
```

**Step 2: run sudo on command as that user**

```
joseph@server:/$ sudo vim test.txt
```

Here I get the prompt for password.

```
[sudo] password for joseph:
```

I want to be able to bypass this prompt without having to change the users sudoers settings.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

yes, that is possible. provided that user `joseph`account is allowed to use `sudo` command, add `NOPASSWD` tag on `/etc/sudoers` file.

it may look like this:

```
joseph ALL = NOPASSWD: /bin/vim
```

see `man 5 sudoers` for more info